# how to use mouse over to show a list properly?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to show a div containing few links
   it shows when I hover perfectly with my code but it doesn't give the
   chance to click on anything as it is now.It just disappears at the point 
   I move the mouse how to handle that??

```
<template>
    <div @mouseover="position" class="hidden1 ">
        <a href="#" class="ss">Locations</a>
        <div class="div1" v-show="block">
            <div class="row pp">
                <a  href="#" class="col-4">East</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4">West</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4">South</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
      <script>
       export default{
           data() {
                return {
                    showHouse: false,
                    par: false,
                    block: false
                }
            },
            methods: {
                position() {
                    this.block = !this.block;

                }
            }
       }
      </script>
```

Comment: You can use `mouseenter` instead. Or, if you need your `position` run only once - use listener as `@mouseenter.once="position"`. If it doesn't help - please clarify your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `mouseover` gets called more that you intend it to as the mouse moves around. There's a case to be made that you should just do this with css and hover. But if you need to do it in Vue, you could use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` like this:

```
<template>
    <div @mouseenter="open" @mouseleave="close" class="hidden1 ">
        <a href="#" class="ss">Locations</a>
        <div class="div1" v-show="block">
            <div class="row pp">
                <a  href="#" class="col-4">East</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4">West</a>
                <a href="#" class="col-4">South</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    name: 'hover',
    data() {
        return {
            showHouse: false,
            par: false,
            block: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        open() {
            this.block = true;
        },
        close() {
            this.block = false;
        }

    }
}
</script>
```